# Connect to WebDAV share with Nautilus in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nautilus, webdav

I tried to connect to a WebDAV share with Nautilus to an URL of the form

```
dav://user@server.company.com:1111/path/to/dir
```

However, I get an error

```
Unhandled error message: HTTP Error: OPTIONS
```

Is the error on my client or the server? How to fix?

**EDIT**: Server providing the WebDAV share is *Sonatype Nexus*.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that you are simply missing an "s" at the end of "dav":

```
davs://user@server.company.com:1111/path/to/dir
```

Incidentally, to check if the server is reachable, you can always go command line with cadaver:

```
cadaver  https://user@server.company.com:1111/path/to/dir
```

One last thing (since at least once a year I tend to need to figure out why Nautilus isn't getting to the old WebDAV bookmarks, and this is the most common answer): If you changed your password on the server, you will need to manually update the saved password on your system via Gnome "Passwords and Keys" (command line "seahorse").

Comment: Thanks, but it's not TLS. The share is provided by *Sonatype Nexus*, it seems to be an interoperabitility problem, but I'd like to know what exactly.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `cadaver` as a way to test, and for the helpful note about passwords. It's a pity this didn't help the questioner, but it's useful information for others (like me) who came looking for a solution to their own problems.